# ObjectListView, Change color of cell depending on property value

Tags: objectlistview

I use ObjectListView in a c# winforms project. My data models have a color-property. In the OLV there is a color-column where i want the backgrounds of the cells be set to the color value of the RowObject. How can i do this? For checkbox columns i can use BooleanCheckStatePutter. Maybe there is something like this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the FormatCell event like this:

```
    private void objectListView1_FormatCell(object sender, FormatCellEventArgs e) {
        // only apply formatting for the desired column
        if (e.ColumnIndex == olvColumn1.Index) {
            // get the model
            Item model = (Item)e.Model;

            // apply back color from model
            e.SubItem.BackColor = model.Color;                
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. This works but the cell shows the color name as text. Is there a way to get blank cells colored individually?

Comment: You probably still have the AspectGetter / AspectName set to the color property name (in the designer or manually). It just calls ToString() on the color. Just remove it and the cell should be empty.

Comment: Yes ... -_-*  Thank you